# Laravel Error In HomeController: Undefined Function showing for all functions

Tags: php, laravel

Ok, so I'm new to Laravel, and I'm working on a new test project.  I'm writing form handling functions in HomeController, and pretty much every built-in function I'm calling is getting an Undefined error.  I'm working in PHPStorm 8, and I've even installed a new Laravel project and copied my views back into the new project, not changing any other Laravel config files.

For example:

```
public function addUser()
{
    $input = Input::all();

    $rules = array('first_name' => 'required',
        'last_name' => 'required',
        'home_location' => 'required',
        'username' => 'unique:username|required',
        'password' => 'required');

    $valid = Validator($input, $rules);

    if ($valid -> passes())
    {
        $user = New User();
        $user->first_name = $input['first_name'];
        $user->last_name = $input['last_name'];
        $user->home_location = $input['home_location'];
        $user->username = $input['username'];
        $password = $input['password'];
        $password = Hash::make($password);
        $user->password = $password;
        $user->save();

        return Redirect::to('admin/');
    } else {
        return Redirect::to('admin/users/')->withInput()->withErrors($valid);
    }
}
```

In this block, Input, Validator, passes, save, and Redirect all report as an error.

Anyone have any clue what in the world is wrong?

Comment: Please share your `routs.php` file

Comment: Is this Laravel 4 or 5?

Comment: I have a suspicion... Is your controller inside a namespace?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your controller is in a namespace. If this is a Laravel 5 project, the default `HomeController` is namespaced to `App\Http\Controllers`. To access classes outside of the namespace, you either need to fully qualify them (e.g. `\Input::all()`), or you need to specify the classes in `use` statements:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Input;
// etc.

class HomeController extends Controller {
```

Other things that I see that may cause errors:

```
// missing "new" keyword:
// $valid = Validator($input, $rules);
$valid = new Validator($input, $rules);
```

If this is Laravel 5, your User model is probably namespaced, so you'll need that as well.

```
$user = new \App\User();
```